# Sending OAuth token works in Postman but does not work in RestSharp

Tags: oauth-2.0, restsharp, auth0

I tried to send a bearer token to an Auth0 API using Postman and it works perfectly.

I then tried the same using  RestSharp (in c#) but it doesn't work at all.

Below is my code. I've tried many different formats but none of them work.. Is there any other way I can try to make it work?

```
var client = new RestClient("http://domain.auth0.com/api/v2/users");

RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
//request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer eyJhbGcJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJ6VU4hVWUE2.token");
//request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");


//RestClient client = new RestClient("http://domain.auth0.com");
//RestRequest request = new RestRequest("api/v2/users", Method.GET);

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("Authorization",
string.Format("Bearer " + "eyJhbGciOI1NiIsI9.eyJhdWQiOiWmVhTWpD2VycyI6eyJhY.token"),
            ParameterType.HttpHeader);

//request.AddParameter(&quot;Authorization&quot;,
//    String.Format(&quot;Bearer {0}&quot;, token),
//ParameterType.HttpHeader);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

PS: the token was changed.

Comment: Thank you for editing my question !  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an HTTP URL. When you issue the first request the token is included, but you receive a redirect response informing that you should be calling the HTTPS endpoint.

Since RestSharp will not include the token in the second request performed automatically due to the first redirect response you get an unauthorized response.

You need to update the URL to be **HTTPS** which will prevent the redirect and as a consequence solve your problem. If you want to make multiple authenticated request using the same client you also change your code to be:

```
using RestSharp;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Use the HTTPS scheme
        var client = new RestClient("https://[domain].auth0.com/api/v2/users");

        client.Authenticator = new OAuth2AuthorizationRequestHeaderAuthenticator(
            "eyJhbGciJIUz.eyJhdWQi4QW5OXhCNTNlNDdjIn0.vnzGPiWA", // Update the token
            "Bearer");

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}", response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

---

If you really need to handle redirects and still send the token, check: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/issues/414

Comment: Thank you João :-)  when I changed to https. I got an "bad request" in my statusCode.  I changed from Web app to a console app, but still get the same result..    Should I try something else?  Do I miss anything here?

Comment: I tested the above code against my Auth0 account with a valid token and it worked correctly. Ensure that you use the latest RestSharp version and the exact same code. If the bad request continues, try to include more information about the response returned.

Comment: This happens also without redirects. Maybe it's different web front end servers working in a cluster, I don't know. Requesting the Auth Token yields the same result both in Postman and RestSharp, but it only works in Postman for an unknown reason.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. There was a redirect to the same resource with a trailing slash missing. Problem solved. Thanks